# How to update a grouped caption in MS-Word?

Tags: ms-word

I have a rather large document with a fair ammount of images and I am facing the following problem:

All images have a caption which looks like this: `Figure 3-2 Paris`. When I add a figure between figure 3-1 and 3-2, I'd like to have the figure updated.

I guess because I group the figure with its caption (so moving the figure around does not mess the position of the caption up) using `ctrl+A` and pressing `F9`does not work. Neither does closing the document and reopening.

My question: Is there any way to update the captions which are inside a group, all at the same time to be sure I won't forget any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

1. Make sure all captions have the same format
2. Select one caption (still possible when caption and figure are grouped
3. Goto: `Start->Edit->Select` choose `Select Text with Similar Formatting`
4. Hit `F9`

You have now updated all captions.

PS. Tested in MS word 2013.